# PHP sorting array based on keys in the order as alphabet then numberic and then special chars

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like below,

```
array(
   [!] = array(),
   [a] = array(),
   [.] = array(),
   [n] = array(),
   [3] = array(),
   [1] = array());
```

I need to sort this array as,

```
array(
   [a] = array(),
   [n] = array(),
   [1] = array(),
   [3] = array(),
   [!] = array(),
   [.] = array());
```

How to do this in php()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;TR

The shortest way (both in terms of code and, after some basic comparisons) is the code I suggest near the *"Demo2"* link below:

```
uksort($arr, function($a, $b)
{
    if (ctype_alnum("$a") === ctype_alnum("$b"))
        return $a > $b;
    return "$a" < "$b";
});
```

---

You can sort an array using the keys with [the `ksort` function](http://www.php.net/ksort):

```
ksort($array, SORT_STRING);
```

The second argument is telling PHP to compare all the keys (including the numeric indexes) as strings (meaning an index like `3` will be treated as if it were `'3'`). This will give you an array where the keys are in *ascending* order. The order of the keys you show (all single characters) will be the same as their respective ASCII values (`.` is 46, `a` is 97 and so on). Seeing as you want to reverse the order, you'll have to use [the `array_reverse` function](http://www.php.net/array_reverse):

```
$array = array_reverse($array, true);
```

Again, the second argument is telling PHP to *preserve the keys*, if not, the indexes will be reset, leaving you with a numerically indexed array.

You can skip the `array_reverse` call quite easily by using [the `uksort`function](http://www.php.net/uksort). It works much the same way as `ksort`, but takes a callback function as a second argument, so you can sort by index, in descending order, too:

```
uksort($arr, function($a, $b)
{
    return "$a" < "$b";//added quotes to convert to strings
});
```

## [Demo](https://eval.in/226204)

You will note that this places the `'.'` key in front of the `'!'` key. In fact, if both keys are of the same type (numeric, alpha), it would appear you want to sort them in ascending order, which you can do easily:

```
uksort($arr, function($a, $b)
{
    if (ctype_alnum("$a") === ctype_alnum("$b"))//both are alnums, sort ascending
        return $a > $b;//sort ascending
    return "$a" < "$b";//else sort descending
});
```

## [Demo2](https://eval.in/226269)

If your PHP version doesn't support anonymous functions, you can define a function and pass its name as second argument, but really: you ought to upgrade:

```
function sortDesc($a, $b)
{
    if (ctype_alnum("$a") === ctype_alnum("$b"))
        return $a > $b;
    return (string) $a < "$b";//casting is valid, too... both do the same thing
}
uksort($array, 'sortDesc');
```

Comment: @Manik: I've checked my result, and addressed the issues. I've updated my answer to reflect this. The resulting array now places `!` in front of `.`, and handles characters and ints correctly. Best of all: I've written it in 4 lines, but you could easily write it as an ugly one-liner (I wouldn't). Either way, it's a lot less code than the accepted answer ATM

Comment: i'm checking ur answer if its work definitely this is the answer.

Comment: @Manik: Remember, it's the `Demo2` link you're after ;-P

Answer (score 2):

```
// function to sort the array keys with
function compare($a, $b)
{
    // Look for [A-z]
    if (ctype_alpha($a)) {
        if (ctype_alpha($b)) {
            return strcasecmp($a, $b);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } elseif (ctype_alpha($b)) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (is_int($a)) {
        if (is_int($b)) {
            return $a > $b;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } elseif (is_int($b)) {
        return 1;
    }

    return $a > $b;
}

$a = array(
   '!' => array(),
   'a' => array(),
   '.' => array(),
   'n' => array(),
   '3' => array(),
   '1' => array()
);

// use the function we defined above to sort the array.
uksort($a, "compare");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
<?php

    $arr = array(
               '!' => array(),
               'a' => array(),
               '.' => array(),
               'n' => array(),
               '3' => array(),
               '1' => array(),
               '$' => array(),
               '8' => array(),
               'm' => array(),
               'x' => array(),
               'c' => array(),
            );

    function mySort($arr){

        $keys = array_keys($arr);
        sort($keys);

        $result = array();
        $temp = array();
        foreach($keys as $key){
            if(!is_numeric($key) && !ctype_alpha($key)){
                $temp[$key] = $arr[$key];
            }else{
                $result[$key] = $arr[$key];
            }
        }
        foreach($temp as $k => $v){
            $result[$k] = $v;
        }
        return $result;

    }


    print_r(mySort($arr));


?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array()
    [c] => Array()
    [m] => Array()
    [n] => Array()
    [x] => Array()
    [1] => Array()
    [3] => Array()
    [8] => Array()
    [!] => Array()
    [$] => Array()
    [.] => Array()
)
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `$result += $temp;` instead of last `foreach`. ;)